# XPATH - getAttribute() and writer.append() to CSV file (Selenium/Selenide)

Tags: java, selenium, csv, xpath, selenide

I'm trying to get "title" attribute value and save it in csv file from element below:

```
<img src="images/i.png" title="Uwagi: łacina, nieczytelne
Data urodzenia: 25.02.1808 r.">
```

Whole html [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTDI7.png).

I've got this attribute value using xpath below (it works):

```
SelenideElement uwagi = $(By.xpath("//div[@id='table_b_wrapper']//table[@id='table_b']//tbody//tr[1]//img[contains(@title,'Uwagi')]"));  
//tr[1] is just a one example from this table. xpath is ok
```

Then I've tried to put it into my csv file with:

```
writer.append(uwagi+";");  //using ; as separator
```

Problem is that this value "Uwagi: łacina, nieczytelne
Data urodzenia: 25.02.1808 r."

It's divided into 2 parts and they are saved as separate cells, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFbyf.png)

I need all this value in one cell  (i.e. J1731 and A1732 values should be as 1 cell).
What's strange when I did  `System.out.println(uwagi.getAttribute("title"));`
only 2nd part of attribute value (Data urodzenia: 25.02.1808 r.) was displayed in console.
How can I save this title attribute value as one cell in csv?

Regards
Tomes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. I've changed:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(pathString, Charset.forName("Cp1250"));
```

to

```
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(pathString, ';', Charset.forName("Cp1250"));
```

using also:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Based on the info from: [link](http://www.seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/java-tutorial/java-csv/300-write-csv-file-in-java)

Then I've changed **writer.apend** to **writer.write**.

Other is the same:

```
...
    SelenideElement xxx = $x("//img[contains(@title,'Uwagi')]"); 
    String str = xxx.getAttribute("title");
    writer.write(str);
...
```

Result: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0QAj.png)

Regards
Tomes

Answer (score 0):

Remove new line character from the title, code below replace `\n` (new line character) with one space as needed per your shared html.
Also in Selenide you can use `$x` for xpath selectors:

```
SelenideElement uwagi = $x("//table[@id='table_b']//tr[@role='row'][1]//img[contains(@title,'Uwagi')]");

//using css selector
uwagi = $("#table_b tr[role='row'] img[title^='Uwagi']");
//or even shorter
uwagi = $("#table_b img[title^='Uwagi']");

String uwagiTitle = uwagi.text().replace("\n", " ");

writer.append(uwagiTitle+";");
```

Comment: Hi, @Sers thanks for quick response. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work.<br/> String uwagiTitle = uwagi.text().replace("\n", " "); returns nothing. I've also tried:   <pre> SelenideElement xxx = $x("//img[contains(@title,'Uwagi')]");
        String str = xxx.getAttribute("title").replace("\n","aa");

        System.out.println(str); <code> <br/> but it also returns only: "Data urodzenia: 25.02.1808 r." instead of "Uwagi: łacina, nieczytelne Data urodzenia: 25.02.1808 r.". Sorry for comment formatting I'm new on stackoverflow.